# cannot install tinytex package. (Maybe the repository setting should be changed.)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

im using R and quite new at rmarkdown. i want to knit my rmarkdown into pdf formatted file and i already read that i need to install tinytex package.
i enter the code as instructed on https://yihui.org/tinytex/

> `install.packages('tinytex')
>
>   tinytex::install_tinytex()`

and i got this error code

> Starting to install TinyTeX to C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX. It will take a few minutes.
>   Automated TeX Live installation using profile: ../tinytex.profile
>   Loading https://mirror.unpad.ac.id/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
>   C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW6xVT8\install-tl-20191206\install-tl: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://mirror.unpad.ac.id/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
>   C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW6xVT8\install-tl-20191206\install-tl: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
>   C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW6xVT8\install-tl-20191206\install-tl: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
>   TinyTeX installed to C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX
>   Please quit and reopen your R session and IDE (if you are using one, such as RStudio or Emacs) and check if tinytex:::is_tinytex() is TRUE.
>   Warning message:
>   In file.remove("TinyTeX/install-tl.log") :
>     cannot remove file 'TinyTeX/install-tl.log', reason 'No such file or directory'

i restart my r and rstudio, run `tinytex::is_tinytex()`, returned FALSE.
i guess the repository cannot be accessed anymore so i tried to change the repo but still it doesnt change.
can anyone help me with solution? thanks

UPDATE :
i tried to run this as [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) told me :

```
tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = 'http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/')
```

and

```
tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = 'http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/')
```

and return this

> trying URL
>   'http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip'
>   length 22539829 bytes (21.5 MB)   downloaded 21.5 MB   trying URL
>   'https://yihui.name/gh/tinytex/tools/pkgs-custom.txt'   Content length
>   81 bytes   downloaded 351 bytes   trying URL
>   'https://yihui.name/gh/tinytex/tools/tinytex.profile'   Content length
>   81 bytes   downloaded 295 bytes   Starting to install TinyTeX to
>   C:\Users\Kandu\AppData\Roaming/TinyTeX. It will take a few minutes.
>   Automated TeX Live installation using profile: ../tinytex.profile
>   Loading 
>   https://mirror.unpad.ac.id/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
>   C:\Users\Kandu\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8OFCvK\install-tl-20191209\install-tl:
>   TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from:
>   https://mirror.unpad.ac.id/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
>   C:\Users\Kandu\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8OFCvK\install-tl-20191209\install-tl:
>   Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
>   C:\Users\Kandu\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8OFCvK\install-tl-20191209\install-tl:
>   More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html TinyTeX installed to
>   C:\Users\Kandu\AppData\Roaming/TinyTeX   Please quit and reopen your R
>   session and IDE (if you are using one, such as RStudio or Emacs) and
>   check if tinytex:::is_tinytex() is TRUE.   Warning messages:
>    1: In
>   file.remove("TinyTeX/install-tl.log") :   cannot remove file
>   'TinyTeX/install-tl.log', reason 'No such file or directory'
>   2: In
>   in_dir(target, { : The repository
>   http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet does not seem
>   to be accessible. Reverting to the default CTAN mirror.

idk why but it keep trying to download from  https://mirror.unpad.ac.id.
any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, the mirror https://mirror.unpad.ac.id does not seem to have a valid SSL certificate, so the site is not accessible. You can find other accessible mirrors at https://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon. To specify the mirror, use the `repository` argument. Below are two possible examples:

```r
tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = 'http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/')

tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = 'http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/')
```

Comment: i already run this with other repository and it still return the same. i will try to run your code sir.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your internet connection (within R). Are you behind a proxy? Anyway, as the last resort, you may try `tinytex:::install_prebuilt()`.

Comment: i tried again this morning. turns out it was fine. maybe the connection to repository is down or i have connection issue when i tried to install at the first time. thanks